# Sony VPCEG brightness issue on Linux Mint 13

Tags: display, linux-mint

I am having a problem reducing the brightness of my screen. It is really hurting my eyes. I have tried to Google the issue but I did not find any solution. Is there a way to reduce the screen brightness in Linux Mint?

I am using a Sony VPCEG laptop and running Linux Mint 13 on it.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Sony Vaio VPCEG and not only with Mint but with other distros I had the same problem, I found a workaround just running a command from the command line interface:

echo 600 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

You will have to enter your administrator password, and you can modify the value 600 is low, I think the maximum is 3300, you will have to play with the values till you find one that suits your needs.

You can use it till someone else corrects the problem with the Fn keys.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my Sony Viao.. Found out about the command..

```
xrandr --output `LVDS_Number` --brightness `Zero_to_One`
```

Replace `LVDS_Number` with your display number (possible LVDS-0 OR LVDS-1). And obviously without -> ` <-

Replace `Zero_to_One` with any value between 0 to 1..It can be 0.1 for 10% brightness or 0.5 for 50% brightness.. And similarly without -> ` <-

---

### To find `LVDS_Number`

`$ xrandr`

**Output :**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

You'll find your LVDS number in the output..
Which in my case is in third line, and is `LVDS-0`

### Sample Syntax

So, to render the brightness to 50%.. We'd use the following command

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS-0 --brightness 0.5
```

Comment: Alternatively you can have SWITCH CASE shell program to render it..